# Tablas temporales

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una duda al crear tablas temporales en un procedimiento, cuando este termina esas tablas ¿se eliminan? o quedan cargadas en cache.

Agradezco la ayuda.

```
    ##################################################### Procedimiento 
    ### limpiar tabla de porcentajes
    delete  from flor_nacional.porcentaje;
    ### sumar campos
    create  temporary table sumatoria  as 
    select 
    ano,NSemana,TFlor,
    sum(Acaros) as acaros,sum(Afidos) as afidos,sum(Babosa) as babosa,sum(Botrytis) as botrytis,
    sum(Fusarium) as fusarium, sum(Hetero) as hetero,sum(Minador) as minador,sum(Trips) as trips,
    sum(Trozador) as trozador,sum(Velloso) as velloso,sum(Abierto) as abierto,sum(DosPuntos) as dospuntos,
    sum(Amarillamiento) as amarillamiento,sum(CabezaPeque) as cabezapeque,sum(Corto) as corto,
    sum(Debil) as debil,sum(Decolorado) as decolorado,sum(Deformado) as deformado,sum(Delgados) as delgados,
    sum(PetaloQuemado) as petaloquemado,sum(PuntasQuemado) as puntasquemado,sum(Rajado) as rajado,
    sum(Torcido) as torcido,sum(Toxicidad) as toxicidad,sum(TInternacional) as tinternacional
    from basecausales 
    group by ano,Nsemana,TFlor;
    
    ### suma total por semana
    create  temporary table TotalSemana  as
    select 
    ano,NSemana,TFlor,
    acaros,afidos,babosa,botrytis,fusarium,hetero,minador,trips,trozador,velloso,
    abierto,dospuntos,amarillamiento,cabezapeque,corto,debil,decolorado,
    deformado,delgados,petaloquemado,puntasquemado,rajado,torcido,toxicidad,
    tinternacional,
    (
    acaros+afidos+babosa+botrytis+fusarium+hetero+minador+trips+trozador+velloso+
    abierto+dospuntos+amarillamiento+cabezapeque+corto+debil+decolorado+deformado+
    delgados+petaloquemado+puntasquemado+rajado+torcido+toxicidad+tinternacional
    ) as TSemana
    from sumatoria 
    group by ano,Nsemana,TFlor;
    
    ### calcular procentajes y guardarlos en tabla porcentaje
    insert into flor_nacional.porcentaje
    select 
    ano,NSemana,TFlor,Tsemana,
    round((acaros/Tsemana)*100,1) as Acaros,
    round((afidos/Tsemana)*100,1) as Afidos,
    round((babosa/Tsemana)*100,1) as Babosa,
    round((botrytis/Tsemana)*100,1) as Botrytis,
    round((fusarium/Tsemana)*100,1) as Fusarium,
    round((hetero/Tsemana)*100,1) as Hetero,
    round((minador/Tsemana)*100,1) as Minador,
    round((trips/Tsemana)*100,1) as Trips,
    round((trozador/Tsemana)*100,1) as Trozador,
    round((velloso/Tsemana)*100,1) as Velloso,
    round((abierto/Tsemana)*100,1) as Abierto,
    round((dospuntos/Tsemana)*100,1) as DosPuntos,
    round((amarillamiento/Tsemana)*100,1) as Amarillamiento,
    round((cabezapeque/Tsemana)*100,1) as CabezaPeque,
    round((corto/Tsemana)*100,1) as Corto,
    round((debil/Tsemana)*100,1) as Debil,
    round((decolorado/Tsemana)*100,1) as Decolorado,
    round((deformado/Tsemana)*100,1) as Deformado,
    round((delgados/Tsemana)*100,1) as Delgados,
    round((petaloquemado/Tsemana)*100,1) as PetaloQuemado,
    round((puntasquemado/Tsemana)*100,1) as PuntasQuemado,
    round((rajado/Tsemana)*100,1) as Rajado,
    round((torcido/Tsemana)*100,1) as Torcido,
    round((toxicidad/Tsemana)*100,1) as Toxicidad,
    round((tinternacional/Tsemana)*100,1) as TInternacional
    from TotalSemana 
    group by ano,Nsemana,TFlor;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySQL tablas temporales que necesitan para ahorrar algo de datos temporal es muy útil. La tabla temporal es visible en la conexión actual, cuando se cierra la conexión, Mysql borrará automáticamente la tabla y liberar todo el espacio.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://www.w3big.com/es/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20tablas%20temporales%20que%20necesitan,y%20liberar%20todo%20el%20espacio.)